# Translate from Coffe (or Type) to vanilla js language

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a part of code on TypeScript or CoffeScript, but I need it on vanilla, can you help me?

```
da.getMatchHistory(options).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}, (errorResponseStatusText) => {
    console.log(errorResponseStatusText);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is javascript with arrows ...

```
da.getMatchHistory(options).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
}, function (errorResponseStatusText) {
   console.log(errorResponseStatusText);
});
```